# How to call a function in a function based ReactJS component?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

In ReactJS would like to have a component from a function, and send a call to a function when a form is posted.
This example doesn't work. How can be fixed?

```
import React from 'react';
import Link from "react-router-dom/Link";

function AddPhoto(props) {

    return (<div>
        <h1>Pickture</h1>
        <Link className='cancelIcon' to="/"> </Link>
        <div>
            <form className="form" onSubmit={e => this.handleSubmit(e)}>
                <input className='.form input' type='text' placeholder='Link' name='link'/>
                <input className='.form input' type='text' placeholder='Description' name='description'/>
                <button> post</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>)

}
export function handleSubmit(event) {
    console.log("Form has been submitted");
    console.log(event.target.element.link.value);
}
```

Comment: Try removing that `-` in your `onSubmit={e => -this.handleSubmit(e)}` and see if it works

Comment: Remove the 'this.' before the handleSubmit. Function components don't use 'this', anyway, you are declaring the function outside of the other function, so even in a class it wouldn't exist within your 'this'.

Comment: what's `this`? do you mean `e => handleSubmit(e)`

Comment: Thanks, I correct it. unfortunately it doesn't solve the problem

Comment: You'll probably also want to export your AddPhoto function, if you want to include your component anywhere. On the other hand, I don't see any reason you would want to export your handleSubmit function.

Comment: What's in console? Keep in mind that default button type is `button`, and it does't submit a form. Try to use `type="submit"` with your button and don't forget to export your component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove `this` from your handleSubmit since it's declared outside.
2. Remove `export` if you're declaring the function in the same file. Otherwise, you would have to define your function in a separate file and then import from there.

   ```
   function AddPhoto(props) {

   return (<div>
       <h1>Pickture</h1>
       <Link className='cancelIcon' to="/"> </Link>
       <div>

    {/* Removed this.*/}
           <form className="form" onSubmit={e => handleSubmit(e)}>
               <input className='.form input' type='text' placeholder='Link' name='link'/>
               <input className='.form input' type='text' placeholder='Description' name='description'/>
               <button> post</button>
           </form>
       </div>
   </div>)

   }

   // Removed export
   function handleSubmit(event) {
     console.log("Form has been submitted");
     console.log(event.target.element.link.value);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 3):

I think there are several issues with your code.

1. You probably want to export your `AddPhoto` component instead of your `handleSubmit` function. Assuming that your file is only exporting your `AddPhoto` component, you don't have to declare a constant and you can straightaway export default your `AddPhoto` function.
2. I actually don't see the reason to export your `handleSubmit` function. So I will include that function inside your `AddPhoto` component.
3. There is a `-` in your `this.handleSubmit` function, also functional component don't have to use `this`, furthermore your `handleSubmit` function is not within your functional component's scope. So it won't work.
4. You probably don't need the `.` in your input `className` props as well.
5. I've formatted your code to make it look cleaner :)

Here are the codes for you to refer.

```
const AddPhoto = (props) => {
  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    // Add this if you want to prevent the page from reloading and updating your url
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("Form has been submitted");
    // Assuming you want to get the `link` field's value, you can get it by using this
    console.log(event.target.link.value);
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Pickture</h1>
      <Link className="cancelIcon" to="/">
        {" "}
      </Link>
      <div>
        <form className="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <input
            className="form input"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Link"
            name="link"
          />
          <input
            className="form input"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Description"
            name="description"
          />
          <button type="submit">post</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default AddPhoto;
```

Comment: This is a decent answer, though some things like the className you might be wrong about. Also, read the OP comments though, the button won't submit the form (missing type=submit / onClick)

Comment: Oddly though, the form is submitted as I've tested locally, but couldn't get the `link` value, I don't want to overkill this question by adding state into it but it seems like it should be the case. For the `className` props yes, that's why I've added `You probably ...` because it's an assumption ! Thanks for pointing that out though

Answer (score 0):

There are quite some issue with your code:

1. The button doesn’t have a type=“submit” on it, so therefor it won’t even submit the form when pressed.
2. HandleSubmit is an function specific to AddPhoto, so it should be inside the AddPhoto component. (I also like to use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) in this case because it should be an anonymous function).
3. There is no need the use `this` because first of all `this` keyword is only used in [classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) to bind functions to the class. So because AddPhoto is an functional component, you don’t have to bind the function to the class.
4. You should add `event.preventDefault();`, because otherwise the page will reload (to submit the form) and you will lose your state of your application.

```
import React from 'react';
import Link from 'react-router-dom/Link';

export default function AddPhoto() {
  const handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const link = event.target.link;
    const description = event.target.description;

    console.log('Form has been submitted');
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Picture</h1>
      <Link className="cancelIcon" to="/">
        cancel
      </Link>
      <div>
        <form className="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <input
            className="form-input"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Link"
            name="link"
            ref={linkInput}
          />
          <input
            className="form-input"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Description"
            name="description"
            ref={descriptionInput}
          />
          <button type="submit">post</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
import React from 'react';
import Link from "react-router-dom/Link";

export function AddPhoto(props) {

    return (<div>
        <h1>Pickture</h1>
        <Link className='cancelIcon' to="/"> </Link>
        <div>
            <form className="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <input className='.form input' type='text' placeholder='Link' name='link'/>
                <input className='.form input' type='text' placeholder='Description' name='description'/>
                <button> post</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>)

}

function handleSubmit(event) {
    console.log("Form has been submitted");
    console.log(event.target.element.link.value);
}
```

Comment: Code dumps are not answers, please explain why your solution works vs what the original poster had in their code.

Answer (score -3):

I think you should be needing to write something like ...

```js
import React from 'react';
import Link from "react-router-dom/Link";

export const AddPhoto = props => {

const handleSubmit = e =>{
return(
    console.log("Form has been submitted");
    console.log(e.target.element.link.value);
)
}

    return (<div>
        <h1>Pickture</h1>
        <Link className='cancelIcon' to="/"> </Link>
        <div>
            <form className="form" onSubmit={e => handleSubmit(e)}>
                <input className='.form input' type='text' placeholder='Link' name='link'/>
                <input className='.form input' type='text' placeholder='Description' name='description'/>
                <button> post</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>)

}

AddPhoto.defaultProps = {

onSubmit: ()=>{}

}
```